# Using Autohotkey to interchange Alt and Cmd keys on Apple keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm doing it right now. Everything works, except one little annoyance: when I press "Win+L" combo to lock PC, the "Win" key remains pressed until I hit it again. The same situation after I enter the password to unlock PC. Can be anything done to get rid of this? Maybe there exists a lower-level key remapping facility in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

[sharpkeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/)

It is a nice piece of software that remaps your keyboard by altering the registry. Been using it for a long time to switch Caps/CTRL.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do you know if it can seamlessly work together with Autohotkey if I use the latter for different, more complex things?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It's actually a lower lever remapping than autohotkey. When writing autohotkey scripts, you just need to take into consideration the remappings already made by sharpkeys.